# get snapshot value angular or firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have this code

```
this.item = db.object('/userProfile', { preserveSnapshot: true });
this.item.subscribe(snapshot => {
  //console.log(snapshot.key)
  console.log(snapshot.child("name/email").key);
});
```

userProfile in firebase is:

userProfile

- EropwlR3LFbpiOLwqUFuasnJ6F72
- PWn2opKFW7VR1n9yGF1aYoggHXk2
- Yo1AKQgzMkgDpb0hLwNMPsMp99m1
- pQCaVtj0B4Rk92ri7LBB1hB0Rkz2

inside: EropwlR3LFbpiOLwqUFuasnJ6F72

- email: example

how to check email value? here is **name** (I have ids: pQCaVtj0B4Rk92ri7LBB1hB0Rkz2)

```
console.log(snapshot.child("name/email").key);
```

this one works if will be name not pQCaVtj0B4Rk92ri7LBB1hB0Rkz2

Comment: I think you have stored id in **name** . So you have to use `console.log(snapshot.child(name+"/email").key);` instead.

Comment: no name here is only example, I have uids. structure: userProfile->EropwlR3LFbpiOLwqUFuasnJ6F72->email: "example@email.com"

Answer (score 0):

This

```
db.object('/userProfile/').valueChanges()
```

should help.

As you know valueChanges() returns all the stored objects and their values.